# deletion in doubly linked list

Tags: c++, pointers, doubly-linked-list

Whenever i call this function my program crashes. I debugged it and it was because of the line of start=start->next; Still couldn't figure where i went wrong. My **start** is a global pointer of node.

```
void double_llist::delete_element(string value)
{
      node *tmp, *q;
      //first element
     if (start->info == value)
     {
         tmp = start;
         start = start->next;
         start->prev = NULL;
         cout<<"Element Deleted"<<endl;
         delete tmp;
         return;
     }

     q = start;
     while (q->next->next != NULL)
     {
         //nth element
         if (q->next->info == value)
         {
             tmp = q->next;
             q->next = tmp->next;
             tmp->next->prev = q;
             cout<<"Element Deleted"<<endl;
             delete tmp;
             return;
         }
         q = q->next;
     }
     //last element
     if (q->next->info == value)
     {
         tmp = q->next;
         delete tmp;
         q->next = NULL;
         cout<<"Element Deleted"<<endl;
         return;
     }
     cout<<"Element "<<value<<" not found"<<endl;
 }
```

Comment: It is not clear from the code whether the list supports also  the tail node or it has only the start node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is too complicated and does not check whether a node is equal to NULL.

For example in general `start` can be equal to NULL or `start->next` can be equal to NULL and so on.

It is enough to consider this code snippet from your function

```
 if (start->info == value)
 {
     tmp = start;
     start = start->next;
     start->prev = NULL;
     cout<<"Element Deleted"<<endl;
     delete tmp;
     return;
 }
```

First of all `start` can be equal to NULL. So this statement

```
if (start->info == value)
```

or this statement

```
start = start->next;
```

is already wrong.

Or `start->next` can be equal to NULL. In this case the second statement in statements below

```
     start = start->next;
     start->prev = NULL;
```

is also wrong.

Take into account that usually double-linked lists support a pointer to the tail (or the end) node.

The function can be written much simpler.

For example

```
void double_llist::delete_element( std::string value )
{
    node *current = start;

    while ( current && current->info != value ) current = current->next;

    if ( current )
    {
        if ( !current->prev )
        {
            start = current->next;
        }
        else
        {
            current->prev->next = current->next;
        }

        if ( !current->next )
        {
            // end = current->prev;
        }
        else
        {
            current->next->prev = current->prev;
        }

        delete current;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Element " << value << " not found" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

In this program I commented one statement that you should uncomment if your list supports a pointer to the last node of the list.

Comment: Thankyou. It was simple mistake of not equating my start to NULL.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your problem could be:

```
if (start->info == value)
{
    tmp = start;
    start = start->next;
    start->prev = NULL;  // This line !!!!!
    cout<<"Element Deleted"<<endl;
    delete tmp;
    return;
}
```

You need to check four `nullptr` before using start.

Maybe this can help:

```
void double_llist::delete_element(string value)
{
     if (start == NULL) return;  // New line

     node *tmp, *q;
     //first element
     if (start->info == value)
     {
         tmp = start;
         start = start->next;
         if (start != NULL)  // New line
         {
             start->prev = NULL;
         }
         cout<<"Element Deleted"<<endl;
         delete tmp;
         return;
     }

     q = start;
     while (q->next->next != NULL)
     {
         //nth element
         if (q->next->info == value)
         {
             tmp = q->next;
             q->next = tmp->next;
             tmp->next->prev = q;
             cout<<"Element Deleted"<<endl;
             delete tmp;
             return;
         }
         q = q->next;
     }
     //last element
     if (q->next->info == value)
     {
         tmp = q->next;
         delete tmp;
         q->next = NULL;
         cout<<"Element Deleted"<<endl;
         return;
     }
     cout<<"Element "<<value<<" not found"<<endl;
 }
```

BTW: I assume this is some kind of homework. If it isn't then stop making your own linked list! Use one of the standard containers, e.g. vector, list, deque, instead.

Comment: Yes it was a homework to make without vectors first.